# WindowsAzure: Is it possible to set directory permissions within the web.config?

Tags: windows, iis, permissions, azure, logging

A PHP scriptof mine wants to write into a log folder, the resulting error is:

> Unable to open the log file "E:\approot\framework\log/dev.log" for writing.

When I set the writing permissions for the WebRole User RD001... manually it works fine.
Now I want to set the folder permissions automatically. Is there an easy way to get it done?
Please note that I'm very new to IIS and the stuff around, I would appreciate precise answers, thx.

Comment: Hou have a slash wrong in `E:\approot\framework\log/dev.log`

There is no way you can configure it to write somewhere else?

Comment: I can change the path, but I don't where the role user has write permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short/Technical Response**:

You could probably set permissions on a particular folder using full-trust and a startup taks.  However, you'd need to account for a stateless OS and changing drive letters (possible, not likely) in this script, which would make it difficult.  Also, local storage is not persisted, so you'd have no way to ensure this data stayed in the case of a reboot.

*Recommendation*: Don't write local, read below ...

EDIT: Got to thinking about this, and while I still recommend against this, there is a 3rd option:  You can allocate local storage in the service config, then access it from PHP using a dll reference, then you will have access to that folder.  Please remember local storage is not persisted, so it's gone during a reboot.

Service Config for local:
http://blogs.mscommunity.net/blogs/dadamec/archive/2008/12/11/azure-reading-and-writing-with-localstorage.aspx

Accessing config from php:
http://phpazure.codeplex.com/discussions/64334?ProjectName=phpazure

---

**Long / Detailed Response:**

In Azure, you really are encouraged to approach things as a platform and not as "software on a server".  What I mean there is that ideas such as "write something to a local log file" are somewhat incompatible with the cloud "idea".  Depending on your usage, you could (and should) convert this script to output this data to some cloud-based or external storage, vs just placing it on the disk.

**I would suggest modifying this script to leverage the PHP Azure SDK and write these log entries out to table or blob storage in Azure.  If this sounds good, please provide the PHP and I can give an exact example.**

The main reason for that (besides pushing the cloud idea) is that in Azure, you cannot assume the host machine ("role instance") will maintain an OS state, so while you can set some things such as folder permissions, you can't rely on them sticking that way. You have no real way to guarantee those permissions won't be reset when the fabric has to update your role and react to some lower level problem.  For example, a hard-drive cage on the rack where your current instance lives could fail.  If the failure were bad enough, the Fabric controller would need to rebuild your instance.  When that happens, your code is moved to an entirely different server, so the need would arise to re-set those permissions.  Also, depending on the changes, the E:\ could all of a sudden need to be the F:\ or X:\ drive and you wouldn't know.

Its much better to pretend (at some level) that your application is running "in Azure" and not "on a server in azure", so you make no assumptions about the hosting environment.  So anything you need outside of your code (data, logs, audits, etc) should be stored somewhere you can control (Azure Storage, external call-out, etc)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I know about the disadvantages of local storage, but in my case there was no other way and non-persitance is no problem. The main reason for my question was storing cache data. First I actually used blob storage but it was too slow for a web application. Azure now offers memcache support, maybe I can used this for my requirements. I'm still wondering why Azure allocates so much local storage (up to 2TB per instance, on a seperate drive) though there is no reasonable usage for it.