# Azure 502 errors .. trying new WebBrowser() and/or image.Save()

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, filesystems, browser

I have this solution that works perfectly on my development workstation using Visual Studio 2012 .Net 4.5. No IIS changes. It's basically C# that grabs a webpage and turns it into bmp.  I'm not sure if my problem is that I'm trying to write to filesystem.

This is what I get in Azure. And I'm reading it might be a limitation/restriction in Azure (Very disappointed if that is the case)

***502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.***

I figure my problem with this code:

```
 public Bitmap GenerateThumbnail()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateThumbnailInteral));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        return ThumbnailImage;
    }
    private void GenerateThumbnailInteral()
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        if (this.Method == ThumbnailMethod.Url)
            webBrowser.Navigate(this.Url);
        else webBrowser.DocumentText = this.Html;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
        webBrowser.Dispose();
    }
```

or maybe with image.save (which might be a problem next).

```
image.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + "/output/"+filename);
```

We are low budget and trying to keeping our hosted site simple and inexpensive. Would rather not have to build a worker process or use storage features of Azure.

===

**UPDATE:**

I don't think my issue is the Save, but do think that will be an issue on Azure. Additionally, as a test, I created a handler ashx that returns a image stream to a html img tag. That too works great locally, but on Azure I just get red Xs. Not sure what's up with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically don't have permissions to do that in Azure to write to the local directory without assigning them.

But there are many solutions to that problem.

Setup your start up task to assign permissions to the directory. 
Worth reading this.
[WindowsAzure: Is it possible to set directory permissions within the web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106179/windowsazure-is-it-possible-to-set-directory-permissions-within-the-web-config)

If you need a temp local drive then this is preferred method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx

If you need a persistent storage then Blob storage would be the best bet.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

You can I believe also attach a drive to the compute like a VHD but I am not sure if two computes can both write to that drive at the same time so you would be maybe best to use blob storage if you need to keep the data.

Blob storage is super cheap.

hths, James

Comment: Thank you for your response. Im pretty sure my error is the WebBrowser control on Azure. For file storage issues I'm anticipating..  I think if i can I'd rather not write the file at all an maybe reder it from a stream which I've been able to do before. That an img pointing to page that reders a  image stream. Not sure if Azure will permit this though.. need to test it, but will still have the issue with WebBrowser.